# ошибка с url register post type

Tags: php, wordpress

Здраствуйте,[image: сам код]у меня в wordpress есть созданный register_post_type там создан архив car (он верный проверял с помощью функции) в нем есть к примеру машинна nissan,(сайт называется wordpress)перехожу по url wordpress/nissan

все верно меня кидает на страницу nissan,и адрес сам подстраивается под wordpress/car/nissan,но когда хочу посмотреть все машины по адресу wordpress/car,то пишет ошибку 404,заходил по гайдам в постоянные ссылки,обновлял вроде ничего не изменилось,подскажите как исправить проблему  или в постоянных ссылкам или каким-нибудь другим способом и подскажите если что в коде сделал неправильно,Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `has_achive` пишется `has_archive`
2. массив `supports` должен быть на одном уровне с массивов `labels` а не в нем.

Подробней о [register_post_type()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type)